# ((())()) is a theorem of PR?

Tags: logic, formal-languages, formal-systems

If we have the following formal system, called PR whose formulas are strings of well-formed parentheses. The language has two symbols '(' and ')'. Any expression is a formula. The only axiom is (). Let $\phi$ and $\psi$ be two formulas of PR; there are three rules of inference:

$$
\frac{\phi}{(\phi)} \ \text{ADD} 
\quad \quad 
\frac{\phi}{\phi \phi} \ \text{DOUBLE} 
\quad \quad
\frac{\phi ( \ ) \psi}{\phi \psi} \ \text{OMIT}
$$

((())()) is a theorem of PR?

Comment: Parentheses do not match.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA Sorry, there was an error due to an extra parenthesis in the above formula. It is now corrected. ((())())

Comment: I've edited your question to use mathjax (which is searchable) rather than an image (which isn't) so that other users have an easier time finding this question. In the future you should do the same ^_^

Comment: @HallaSurvivor Thank you so much I will keep it in mind

Comment: You say "formulas" in the first sentence, but I think you might have meant "theorems"

Comment: Please don't rely on the title of your MSE questions for important information. The body should be self-contained: the title is just for reference. In this you have to read the entire body of your question to be in a position to figure what the question actually means. Some MSE interfaces may not render maths in the title properly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's a hint:

Recall that *any expression is a formula*. In particular, $\phi = {(())(}$  and $\psi = {)}$ are both formulas, so that one instance of OMIT is

$$
\frac{\phi (\ ) \psi}{\phi \psi} = \frac{(())( \ \ ( \ ) \ \ )}{(())()}
$$

This is counterintuitive, since you have to work with expressions with unmatched parentheses in the middle of your derivation, but is completely allowable from the rules you've stated. Do you see how to finish from here?

(As an aside, I suspect if you require $\phi$ and $\psi$ to be theorems at every intermediate stage, then $((())())$ will *not* be a theorem, but I don't have time to work on a proof right now.)

---

I hope this helps ^_^

Comment: Thank you so much, I got it!

Comment: Nice answer! RE: your aside... I think it will depend a bit on exactly what you mean by "theorems" (eg if that means "theorem from the old system" or if it's a self-referential bootstrapped situation). But in any case, $\phi$ and $\psi$ would always have to have balanced parentheses. Therefore OMIT only ever applies to a $()$ not contained in any other parentheses. In particular as soon as you do an ADD you can only get bigger, and can never OMIT again. So working backwards shows you'd need to get to $(())()$, but this cannot be formed from any balanced string by doubling or adding.